# Error Unknown file extension ".css" en aplicación con React, Jest y Vitest

Tags: reactjs, vite, vitest

Tengo una app desarrollada en React, Vite y Vitest, pero cuando corro las pruebas unitarias me sale el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: Unknown file extension ".css" for archivo.css

Serialized Error: {
    "code": "ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION",
}
```

He consultado mucho en internet como resolverlo y nada ha funcionado.

Esta es la configuración de Vite.

```
export default defineConfig(() => ({
  base: '', // relative paths
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    ckeditor5({
      theme: require.resolve('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark'),
    }),
  ],
  test: {
    environment: 'happy-dom',
  },
}))
```

Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Comment: y el archivo.css??

Comment: ¿Probaste [esta solución](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/5283#issuecomment-1962265873)?

Comment: @Marcos hola, si y no funciona, eso me daña todas las pruebas, me sale el siguiente error: "Error: No test suite found in file"

Comment: Si te fijas en el error aparece algo como extension desconocida 'css' para 'archivo.css', primeramente me validaría que estoy poniendo bien la ruta para archivo.css

Comment: En dónde en tu proyecto se hace referencia a `archivo.css`?

Comment: ***https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/614124/error-unknown-file-extension-css-en-aplicaci%c3%b3n-con-react-jest-y-vitest***

Answer (score 0):

Eventualmente podrías agregar un **plugin** a tu `vite.config` si todos los directorios y el `archivo.css` está correctamente importado y/o exportado.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import css from 'vite-plugin-css';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), css()],
});
```

También recuerda que a **Vite** no le gustan las importaciones de React `import react from 'react';`

Espero haberte ayudado al menos un poco!

Un saludote!

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que tu problema esté relacionado con la declaración de tipos.
Verifica en tu **tsconfig.json** que esté incluido el archivo **tsconfig.node.json** que a su vez debe incluir el archivo **vite.config.ts**

Así deberían de verse tus archivos, fijate bien en las ultimas lineas el **references** en el **config.json** y en el **include** en el **tsconfig.node.json**

*tsconfig.json*

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

*tsconfi.node.json*

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

Si por algún motivo eliminaste el tsconfig.node.json
considera agregar en tu rsconfig.json lo siguiente

```json
{
    "compilerOptions":{
     //Esto dejalo como está
    },
    "include": ["src", "src/vite-env.d.ts"]
}
```